# EntityManger null in seam unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, seam, entitymanager

Below is the code I am trying to test, but getting null pointer exception on entityManager.find coz entityManager = null. Any suggestions?

```
@Name("UserProfileConverter")
@BypassInterceptors
@Converter(forClass= UserProfile.class)
public class UserProfileConverter implements javax.faces.convert.Converter {

    @Logger
    private static Log logger;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
           EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) Component.getInstance("entityManager");

        UserProfile p;

        if(s == null || s.equals("null")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                long i = Long.parseLong(s);
                return entityManager.find(UserProfile.class, i);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComponetn, Object arg2) {
        return ((CsaRole)arg2).getCsaRoleId() + "";
    }

}
```

Here is my test class..

```
public class UserProfileConverterTest extends SeamTest {

    private UserProfileConverter converter;
      private FacesContext mockFacesContext;
      private UIComponent mockUiComponent;

      private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserProfileConverterTest.class);

      @BeforeClass
      public void setup() {
          converter = new UserProfileConverter();
      }
      @Test
      public void testGetAsObject()
              throws Exception {
              new ComponentTest() {

              @Override
              protected void testComponents() throws Exception {

              String value =   "11111111111";
              converter.getAsObject(mockFacesContext, mockUiComponent, value);

              }
          }.run();
      }


}
```

Comment: Well, it's obviously null because no component of this type exist. What is the infrastructure you are running your tests in?

Comment: We are using TestNG and Seam, if thats what you mean by infrastructure.

Comment: No, question was rather if you are running this test in some sort of embedded container? Because: Someone has to initalize the entitymanager for the test - that can be either you, your testing framework or application server...

Comment: i guess I will need an embedded jboss container to run locally. will that also help me getting any component eg., `Component.getInstance("MyClass");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public class UserProfileConverterTest extends SeamTest {
>
> ```
> EntityManager mockEntityManager;
> private UserProfileConverter converter;
> UIComponent mockUiComponent = null;
> MockFacesContext mockFacesContext = null;
>
> @BeforeClass
> public void setup() {
>     converter = new CsaUserProfileConverter();
>     mockEntityManager = EasyMock.createMock(EntityManager.class);
> }
>
>
> class BaseComponentTest extends ComponentTest {
>
>     protected void testComponents() throws Exception {
>
>     ScopeType.EVENT.getContext().set("entityManager", mockEntityManager);
>     }
> }
>
> @Test
> public void testGetAsObject() throws Exception {
>     new BaseComponentTest() {
>         protected void testComponents() throws Exception {
>             super.testComponents();
>
>         UserProfile expectedResult = new UserProfile();
>         EasyMock.expect(mockEntityManager.find(UserProfile.class,1L)).andReturn(expectedResult);
>
>
>         //Replay Mock 
>         EasyMock.replay(mockEntityManager);
>
>         Object target = converter.getAsObject(mockFacesContext,mockUiComponent,"1");
>         Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, target);
>
>         //Verify the Mock 
>         EasyMock.verify(mockEntityManager);
>
>         }
>     }.run();
> }
> ```